# Помогите процедурщику переписать маленький скриптик на javascript в ООП стиле

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть код

```js
function popup(){}
popup.hello = function(){
  $("#container").html('<div onclick="popup.bye()">Hello</div>')
}
popup.bye = function(){
  alert("Bye");
}

popup.hello()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Как ни пробовал его сделать через классы, модули или вообще в ООП стиле, ничего не получается.

---

Так, чтобы не было лишних вопросов с лишним кодом и минусов, решил сделать пример более наглядным

```js
var module =(function (){
var instanceCount = 0;
var CONSTANT_GlOBAL = Math.random();
function render(localRandom){
   $("#container").append('\
  <div onclick="module.create('+ instanceCount++ +')">\
   Module №: '+ instanceCount +'\
   <br>Instance random variable: '+localRandom+'\
   <br>Module random constant: '+ CONSTANT_GlOBAL +'\
  </div><br>');
}
return {
 run: function(number){
  var localRandom = Math.random();
  render(localRandom,number);
 },
   create: function(number){
    this.run(number);
 }
}
}());

module.run(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: А зачем тут ООП?

Comment: Затем, что вскоре появится колбаса из
popup.method1,
popup.method2,
popup.method3,
popup.property1...и т.д.
 Хочется инкапсуляции в пределах функции с конструктором.

Comment: @АлексейАлексеев я ответил на ваш вопрос [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33844976#33844976).

Comment: @Codd Wrench, Так я и хотел увидеть как можно засунуть вызов функции класса в определение класса. Если бы я мог сам создать,  я бы создал. Что надо писать в <button onclick="???"></button>, когда этот html тоже внутри одной из функций класса?

Comment: @АлексейАлексеев смотрите строчку `element.find("a.close").click(`

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример кода, куда надо вставить хоть и надуманный, но отражающий суть, кусок кода: Popup.render(){$el.html('<button onclick="Popup.show()"></button>')}. Вот у меня внутрь класса он никак не засовывается. У Вас обработчик тоже вне класса.

Comment: @АлексейАлексеев, сформулируйте и создайте еще один вопрос.

Comment: @Codd Wrench, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599041/221114. Вот, я ответил сам себе. Пока такой подход меня полностью устраивает. Все в одной сущности. Наследоваться я пока не собираюсь, это было избыточно.

Answer (score 6):

Вообще реализация чистого ООП подхода на js, *до стандарта es6*, это одна из самых нетривиальных задач и поэтому у нее есть множество вариантов решения:

### Вариант 1 - найти подходящую js библиотеку

Таких библиотек в интернете множество, вот пара примеров:

- [jsface](https://github.com/tnhu/jsface)
- [classify](http://classify.petebrowne.com/#/usage/methods)

### Вариант 2 - использовать js compiler

Тоже множество вариантов, например:

- [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) - компилирует(транслирует) ванильный es6 код.
- [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org) - отдельное надмножество js, позиционируемый как js c типами.

### Вариант 3 - написать свою реализацию

В ответах уже [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597065/211480) простейшая реализация класса с использованием [module-pattern](http://largescalejs.ru/module-pattern/), но ООП на этом не заканчивается, а какже наследование? В js уже реализован механизм наследования через prototype вот так:

```
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
```

Но это скопирует только методы прототипа, а у нас есть еще свойства самого объекта - в ООП это статические методы и свойства, поэтому я использую следующий паттерн:

```
function extend(current, base) {
    // копируем статические проперти
    for (var key in base) {
        if (base.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            current[key] = base[key];
        }
    }

    // копируем прототип
    current.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);

};
```

Теперь можно это использовать:

```
var Dialogs;
(function (Dialogs) {

    // класс Popup
    Dialogs.Popup = (function () {
        // статическая функция
        Popup.show = function () {
            alert("show");
        };
        // Конструктор класса
        function Popup(message) {
            this._message = message;
        }
        Popup.prototype.hello = function () {
            var self = this;
            var message = $(this._message).click(function () {
                    self.sayBye();
                });
            $("#container").append(message);
        };
        Popup.prototype.sayBye = function () {
            alert("Bye");
        };
        Popup.prototype.say = function () {
            alert(this._message);
        };
        return Popup;
    }());

    // класс Popup2 extend Popup
    Dialogs.Popup2 = (function (superClass) {
        // наследуем прототип
        extend(Popup2, superClass);
        function Popup2() {
            // вызываем конструктор базового класса
            superClass.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        // перегружаем базовую функцию sayBye 
        Popup2.prototype.sayBye = function () {
            alert("Bye2");
        };
        return Popup2;
    }(Dialogs.Popup)); // передаем базовый класс

})(Dialogs || (Dialogs = {}));
```

В коде ваше создается область видимости(namespace) Dialogs внутри которой происходит вся магия, так же в ней можно объявлять глобальные переменные:

```
var Dialogs;
    (function (Dialogs) {
        var a = 100; // переменная видна внутри Dialogs
        Dialogs.b = 100; // можно обратиться как к Dialogs.b снаружи
        ...
```

Можно конечно и без нее тогда паттерн класса будет выглядеть так:

```
var Popup2 = (function (superClass) {
    extend(Popup2, superClass);
    function Popup2() {
        superClass.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return Popup2;
}(Popup));
```

посмотреть как это работает можно тут: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dy0emm9t/)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49294/discussion-on-answer-by-codd-wrench-----).

Comment: Как будто в es6 что-то кроме косметики добавилось в плане поддержки ООП.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, я не утверждал что es6 решает все проблемы, просто с его появлением писать ООП код стало более тривиально.

Comment: Что именно в es6 делает написание ООП более тривиальным?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian синтаксический сахар - ключевые слова `class`, `extends` и т.д [подробнее тут](https://www.sitepoint.com/object-oriented-javascript-deep-dive-es6-classes/). То есть, необходимость использовать инструменты из первых пунктов отпадает.

Answer (score 2):

А React использовать можно?

```js
class Popup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.bye = this.bye.bind(this);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.bye}>{this.props.msg}</div>;
  }
  
  bye() {
    alert("Bye");
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Popup msg="Hello"/>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Нет, ванильный js с jQuery. Но направление мне нравится.

Comment: А чего минусы-то посыпались? Класс DOM-элемента React выглядит очень даже адекватной абстракцией для описанного в вопросе объекта `popup`. Конечно, ради такого мелкого примера тянуть целый React не стоит, но автор же явно подчеркнул, что пример игрушечный и объект имеет все шансы здорово разрастись.

Comment: Все верно. Но реакт натягивать - переписывать все приложение.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Popup = function () {
    this.hello = function() {
      $("#container").html('<div onclick="popup.bye()">Hello</div>')
    },
    this.bye = function(){
      alert("Bye");
    }
}

var popup = new Popup;

popup.bye()
```

Comment: `onclick="popup.bye()"` - привязка к глобальной переменной - это просто шикарное ООП.

Comment: @Qwertiy Эту проблему ему самому придется решать) так как работать не будет.

Comment: вообще-то, именно от вас решение-то ожидалось...

Comment: Пробовал. Но зашивать инстанс в конструктор для меня недопустимо.